# Unable to capture screenshot in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, automation, screenshot, extentreports

I am trying to capture screenshot in Selenium, However I am getting an error on -**File source = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);** I have searched the code online and it they have given it as it is. Now I don't know what should be replaced with this code. The error I am getting is- FILE cannot be resolved or is not a field. My full code is:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import com.aventstack.extentreports.Status;
import com.google.common.io.Files;
import com.mongodb.MapReduceCommand.OutputType;

public class UtilityMethods extends ExtentReportBaseClass{

    static WebDriver driver;

    public static WebDriver openBrowser(String browsers) {

        System.out.println("initiated browser is " + browsers);
        if (browsers.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {

            System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "");

            DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();

            dc.setCapability("marionatte", false);
            FirefoxOptions opt = new FirefoxOptions();
            opt.merge(dc);
            driver = new FirefoxDriver(opt);

        }

        else if (browsers.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome")) {
            // String driverPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") +
            // "\\src\\Drivers\\chromedriver";
            // System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath);
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        }

        return driver;

    }

    public static void launchWebsite(String URL) {
        driver.get(URL);

    }

    public static By locateByElement(String locator, String locatorValue) {
        By by = null;

        switch (locator) {

        case "id":
            by = By.id(locatorValue);
            break;

        case "name":
            by = By.name(locatorValue);

            break;
        case "linktext":
            by = By.linkText(locatorValue);
            break;
        case "partialLinkText":
            by = By.partialLinkText(locatorValue);
            break;

        case "className":
            by = By.className(locatorValue);
            break;

        case "tagName":
            by = By.tagName(locatorValue);
            break;

        case "cssSelector":
            by = By.cssSelector(locatorValue);
            break;

        case "xpath":
            by = By.xpath(locatorValue);
            break;

        }
        System.out.println("value of by is" + by);
        return by;

    }

    public void sendDataById(String locatorValue, String userData) {

        driver.findElement(By.id(locatorValue)).sendKeys(userData);

    }

    public void sendData(String element) {
        String[] var = element.split("###");

        String loctype = var[0];
        String locval = var[1];
        // System.out.println(locval);
        String uservalue = var[2];
        // System.out.println(locval);
        // System.out.println(uservalue);

        By locator = locateByElement(loctype, locval);
        System.out.println(loctype);
        System.out.println(locval);
        driver.findElement(locator).sendKeys(uservalue);

    }

    public  WebDriver getdriver() {
        if (driver == null) {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            return driver;
        } else {
            return driver;
        }
    }

    public static String capture(WebDriver driver,String screenShotName) throws IOException
    {
        TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot)driver;
        File source = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        String dest = System.getProperty("user.dir") +"/TestCasesScreenshot"+screenShotName+".png";
        File destination = new File(dest);
        Files.copy(source, destination);        

        return dest;
    }

    public void clickElement(String locElem) throws IOException {

        try {

        System.out.println(locElem);
        String[] var = locElem.split("###");
        String loctype = var[0];
        String locval = var[1];
        System.out.println(loctype);
        System.out.println(locval);
        By locator = locateByElement(loctype, locval);

        driver.findElement(locator).click();
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Catched Exception, Element not found");
            String screenShotPath = UtilityMethods.capture(driver, "screenShotName");
            test.log(Status.FAIL, "Snapshot below: " + test.addScreenCaptureFromPath(screenShotPath));
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import selenium's `OutputType`. Use this -- `import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType`. Currently you have a mongodb class import.